# Show and Hide Product Grid in custom module Magento 2

Tags: javascript, adminhtml, uicomponent, adminform

I have created a drop down field. When I select 1 option from field I want to show the another field and along with that I want to hide product grid.
Same as when I select 2nd opinion, I want to show product grid and the field should be hide.

I have used **js code**. That is working fine for fields by getting field name in JS. But I don't know how do I get the Product Grid name in JS file.

Any help please..

Answer (score 0):

Open inspector in browser , search for columns that you need to hide and just in js check your value 1/0 and if you need to hide grid or columns use js code like this :
$(#id or class name).hide() or you can use .css('display','none') or .attr().

Check documentation about this js features. It is very easy to use .